# new 'maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'' error with no change to app.config or web.config

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

We recently got an 'maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'. Change the object graph or increase the MaxItemsInObjectGraph.' error on our production environment after deploying a new version of our code.

I checked the app.config and web.config files and nothing seems different between the old version and new version.  Our version control reports a single change:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
```

Changed to

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="52428800"/>
```

The app.config has always had MaxItemsInObjectGraph set:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAppService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AppServiceBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="LargeObjectGraphBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>        

    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/AppService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAppService"
            contract="PlaybookService.IAppService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAppService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Our web.config never makes a reference to maxItemsInObjectGaph, but we have never had a problem here before.  Here it is anyway:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="App" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Everything works locally, and in the test environment, which all have the same size tables.  The old version has always worked with nearly identical config files.

Does anyone have an idea on what could be causing this?

Comment: Something that stands out is the fact that `2147483647` is aligned with many of the config values already in place.  The new value is smaller.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey is that a bad practice or will that cause errors?

Comment: Just an observation.  If two of the elements are related (Say maybe httpRuntime and basicHttpBinding) then it could be an issue if the two do not matchup.  The default is 65536 I believe.  So it appears that the default value quit working for some unknown reason.  Maybe you can just set your values explicitly to a high value.  Are you sure you didn't do something like upgrade .NET versions?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Yeah .NET Version is the same it has always been.  If this error can't originate from anything other than the config files, is it safe to assume that the only change we had made, changing the maxRequestLength, is the cause of this error?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.  However, maybe another factor is involved.  I recommend rolling back the code to the previous version (or grabbing the original DLL's) and see if the error goes away.  That should be enough to confirm it is indeed the code change.